# web Service With Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services

In My App I Wanna retrieve All Stores Near To The Curent Location in Egypt .
i used Google Places API But It Doesn't Give Me What I Need And It Has Only 20 Store .
any One Can Help Me With Web Service free Or Data Bas I Can Access .
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that data does not exist in any form other than Google Places API you may be out of luck.  I would recommend this site to search for APIs. http://www.programmableweb.com/apis

If programmableweb.com doesn't help I would recommend seeking out a company that perhaps creates business directories for Egypt.  Assuming they are willing to work with you, you may end up needing to build the API all on your own.